# Windows 10 on AMD Athlon XP 2600+ (AXDA2600DKV4D

Tags: windows-10, windows-installation

Hi I am running  AMD Athlon XP 2600+ on 1.97Ghz on Asus A7V600 with 1 GB RAM (will upgrade to 3) and 120GB 7200 HDD. Currently it runs XP, but it used to run Windows 7 as well. XP feels quite sluggish and I am thinking on upgrading to Windows 10.

I am wondering if this hardware will support it. According to MS specs, it needs 1Ghz CPU and 1GB of RAM.

Comment: **Every** modern Desktop environment will feel sluggish on nearly 20 years old hardware! AXDA2600DKV4D was introduced in 2002 and runs on DDR1

Comment: It would be recommended to run a Linux distro on that setup, not Windows, preferably with at least 4GB of RAM. While those are the minimum requirements for Windows to run, unless you have a quad-core >2GHz CPU and 16GB of RAM, Windows will be sluggish since it's resource-intensive due to the number of services it runs by default. Install a Linux distro matched to your specs and you'll be much happier with the end result, as Linux isn't resource-intensive by default.

Comment: Windows 10 has very specific processor requirements.  It’s not guaranteed that your system will even support Windows 10.  Given the age of that processor, it’s extremely unlikely, your system can even run Windows 10

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10 (if you can run it on this machine) will be very slow. You would probably want Windows 10 32-bit with only 3 GB of memory.

You said it ran Windows 7 very slowly. Windows 10 will not be much faster on this hardware.

All you can do is try.

The machine will likely feel slow in normal use.

Comment: HDD is 7200rpm. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Computers need to be ***considerably*** more powerful to run Win 10 even at base spec than something needed for WinXP. If it was slow on XP it will be almost stopped on Win 10.

I doubt it will even install on a chip that old. It won't have such as PAE/SS02 and NX

Even if you could force it on, if your GPU is as old as the rest of the machine, there will be no drivers for it… nor probably most of the rest of the hardware.

I wouldn't bother, it will not be a happy experience even if you manage it.

You could buy a better machine, capable of just about struggling along with a minimum spec Windows 10, for under $£€ 50 from a junk shop.